# Help synchronize on unknown frequency sequence

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, bandwidth

I am having trouble to synchronize on a frequency hopping pattern between an emitter `Tx` and a receiver `Rx`. More precisely, the communication between `Tx` and `Rx` uses frequency hopping spread spectrum (`FHSS`) in the 2.4GHz - 2.485GHz ISM band, and I would like another `Rx` to be able to synchronize on the `Tx`.

To do so, I thought of cutting the entire bandwidth in a set of smaller ones and, if the energy contained in one of the smaller bands is greater than the mean of the energy of all the bands, it means I have a signal in that band and that I have to use that frequency. Using `GNU Radio (3.8.3.1)`, a [LimeSDR](https://limemicro.com/products/boards/limesdr/) is connected to a `polyphase filter bank` (where each filter is a low-pass one) block, each of the outputs connected to a `Stream to Vector` block, a `Complex to Mag Squared` block, a `threshold` block, and finally some sinks to see the result. So far, I could not achieve satisfying results, and was wondering if

1. the proposed method made sense ?
2. it was possible to have a "dynamic" threshold to adapt to noisy environments and put the computed mean energy as threshold ?
3. I use the `polyphase filter bank` block correctly ?

[Here](https://github.com/aheuchamps/sandbox-repo/blob/main/test_synchro_01.py) is a link to the code using the [LimeSDR](https://limemicro.com/products/boards/limesdr/), and [here](https://github.com/aheuchamps/sandbox-repo/blob/main/test_synchro_02.py) is a code using a perdiodic band sweeper used to see if what I am trying makes sense.

Thank you and have a nice day, Alex.

Comment: This question is on-topic here, but honestly, it's very much the focus of [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com), and there's more estimation theory, detection, digital filtering… experts over there. Might just be a better place to ask! I still think it fits here, it's really just because I think you might get a broader feedback.

Comment: If the frequency hopping sequence is quasi random with a really long period, then you may not be able to synchronize. Such systems have been used in security applications.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer @MarcusMüller, have a nice day. Alex

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg thank you for your answer. I thought so but still wanted to try. Have a nice day, Alex

Answer (score 1):

> 1. the proposed method made sense ?

Sounds good. If you were a student of mine, I had you sit down and write down the probability of missing something due to white noise being stronger on the non-signal bands, and the probability of misinterpreting noise as occupancy. (the latter is easier.)

This has to be done with SNR as a parameter (hint: you can fix the noise power to be 1 and just vary the $\sigma^2$ of noise).

That way, you can evaluate *how* sensible your approach is, in numbers.

> 2. it was possible to have a "dynamic" threshold to adapt to noisy environments and put the computed mean energy as threshold ?

Sure! That's what you described in 1.

> 3. I use the polyphase filter bank block correctly ?

Probably, it's kind of hard to reconstruct it from the Python alone